# ruby regex for multiple words conditionally match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I want to remove all prefix of names. (e.g. Prof., Dr., Mr. etc.) which can be more than one in any sequence. So I want to write a regex which will `slice` all of these prefixes. I want to do this in `ruby`.

Following are input/output set which I want to achieve.

```
"Prof. Dr. John Doe" => "John Doe"
"Dr. Prin. Gloria Smith" => "Gloria Smith"
"Dr. William" => "William"
"Sean Paul" => "Sean Paul"
```

I also want to store removed prefixes in another string.

```
"Prof. Dr. John Doe" => "Prof. Dr."
"Dr. Prin. Gloria Smith" => "Dr. Prin."
"Dr. William" => "Dr."
"Sean Paul" => ""
```

Comment: Don't just blur it with "etc". State clearly what the prefixes are that you are concerned with.

Comment: @sawa there can n no. of prefixes, all of them can't be mentioned, so consider is an array.

Comment: How can you remove what you can't mention?

Comment: @sawa: The question becomes lengthy which I think is not needed. What I need is logic.

Comment: Are you sure that there is always a dot after the abbreviation? Or might they also write "Dr Sean Paul"? Is is possible that the space is left, like "Dr.William"?

Comment: @Meier, "Dr" without the period is not grammatically correct, but you are right that there are titles that do not end with a period, such as "The Grand Pubah Karsten Meier". I think it would be hopeless to try to parse those without a list of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the prefixes are only `Prof.`, `Dr.`, `Mr.`, `Mrs.`, `Prin.`, `Ms.` you can try:

```
s = "Prof. Dr. John Doe"
s.gsub(/Prof.|Dr.|Mr.|Mrs.|Prin.|Ms./, "").strip
```

For second question(want to store removed prefixes in another string)

```
 s = "Prof. Dr. John Doe"
 s.scan(/Prof.|Dr.|Mr.|Mrs.|Prin.|Ms./).join("")
 => "Prof.Dr."
```

Comment: I also want to store removed prefixes in another string.

Comment: Dr. Dre completely disappears .

Comment: Suppose `name  #=>  "John Doe"` is returned in the first part. Then, for the second part, `s[0,s.size-name.size].rstrip #=> "Prof. Dr."`.

Answer (score 6):

**Case 1: list of titles is given**

Suppose

```
titles = ["Dr.", "Prof.", "Mr.", "Mrs.", "Ms.", "Her Worship", "The Grand Poobah"]

R = /
    (?:   # begin non-capture group
      #{Regexp.union(titles)}
          # "or" all the titles
      \s* # match >= 0 spaces
    )*    # end non-capture group and perform >= 0 times
    /x    # free-spacing regex definition mode
  #=> /
  #   (?:   # begin non-capture group
  #     (?-mix:Dr\.|Prof\.|Mr\.|Mrs\.|Ms\.|Her\ Worship|The\ Grand\ Poobah)
  #         # "or" all the titles
  #     \s* # match >= 0 spaces
  #   )*    # end non-capture group and perform >= 0 times
  #  /x 

def extract_titles(str)
  t = str[R] || ''
  [str[t.size..-1], t.rstrip] 
end

["Prof. Dr. John J. Doe, Jr.", "Dr. Prin. Gloria Smith", "The Grand Poobah Dr. No",
  "Gloria Smith", "Cher, Ph.D."].each { |s| p extract_titles s }
  # ["John J. Doe, Jr.", "Prof. Dr."]
  # ["Prin. Gloria Smith", "Dr."]
  # ["No", "The Grand Poobah Dr."]
  # ["Gloria Smith", ""]
  # ["Cher, Ph.D.", ""]
```

If there are no titles, as in the last two examples, `str[R] => nil`, so `(str[R] || "").rstrip #=> "".rstrip #=> ""`.

See the doc for the class method [Regexp::union](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Regexp.html#method-c-union) to see how it's used.

**Case 2: there is no list of titles**

The following assumes that all titles are a single word beginning with a capital letter, followed by one or more lowercase letters, followed by a period. If that is not correct, the regex below can be changed accordingly.

The only difference between this case and previous one is that the regex changes.

```
R = /
    \A       # match beginning of string
    (?:      # start a non-capture group
      [A-Z]  # match a capital letter
      [a-z]+ # match > 0 lower-case letters
      \.\s*  # match a period followed by >= 0 spaces
    )*       # end non-capture group and execute >= 0 times
    /x       # free-spacing regex definition mode

["Prof. Dr. John J. Doe, Jr.", "Dr.Prin.Gloria Smith",
 "Gloria Smith", "Cher, Ph.D."].each { |s| p extract_titles(s) }
  # ["John J. Doe, Jr.", "Prof. Dr."]
  # ["Gloria Smith", "Dr. Prin."]
  # ["Gloria Smith", ""]
  # ["Cher, Ph.D.", ""]
```

Comment: I feel like this is a better answer. Great use of Regex.

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked for regex:

```
str = "Prof. Dr. John Doe"
str.remove(/((Dr|Mr|Prof|Prin)\.? ?)/i)
```

This will result in:

```
"John Doe"
```

This will match with or without the period (Dr or Dr.)
Also, the 'i' at the end will make it match lowercase 'dr' and 'prof'.

Comment: @RajarshiDas Looks like a Rails method, which OP has tagged for.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
"Dr. Prin. Gloria Smith".split(". ").last
"Prof. Dr. John Doe".split(". ").last
```

Comment: This will not work in some cases. The name can be 'Gloria A. Smith'

Answer (score 0):

If there is always a dot(.) after the prefix then you can use the below logic

```
s = "Prof. Dr. John Doe"
match = s.match(/([\w\s\.]+\.)?\s*([\w\s]+)/)
prefix = match[1]
name = match[2]
```

OR

if you were to have a dictionary of all the prefixes

```
s = "Prof. Dr. John Doe"
dictionary = ['Prof\.', 'Dr\.', 'Mr\.', 'Mrs\.', 'Prin\.'].join('|\s*')
match = s.match(/((?:#{dictionary})*)\s*([\w\s\.]+)/)
prefix = match[1]
name = match[2]
```

as you can see in the above array (dictionary) the prefixes have the dot(.) escaped as dot(.) in regex has a different meaning i.e its metacharacter which represents any character http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html

Comment: @Datta let me know if any clarification needed on what the regex means